# qooxdoo : protected / private properties?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have an Object class that has a property called `counter`. Can I set it as private or protected, i.e. `this._counter` or `this.__counter` ?

```
qx.Class.define("myApp.model.MyClass",
{
  extend : qx.core.Object,
  construct : function() {
  },
  properties : {
    counter : { init : '', check : 'Integer' }
  }
});
```

Properties is good , as it enables automatic generation of `getCounter()` and `setCounter(val)`.

But is there any disadvantage to set it as public properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but setting a property to private or protected is not possible. You have to use a member variable instead and either access it directly or write your own setter / getter.

Comment: But is there any disadvantage (e.g. security problem) to set it as public properties ?

Comment: No. When you use properties you **do** want this exposure. Properties are a modelling feature. If you want hidden data in a class, don't use properties.